# Angular 4 How to call funtion from .js file in .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular

I work on a project in newest version of Angular4. When user press enter while in input field he activates a method pressed(). I also want to call a function from external .js file located in /assets folder. I didn't want to rewrite whole script to match .ts format so I just linked my .js file to index.html to make it work.

That .js file contains SVG script which manipulates several DOM elements. I want to call a function that will destroy these elements.

**My question is as simple as that:** How do i tell angular4 to recognise elements from .js to make calling .js methods avaiable from .ts file?

[Call funtion from dots.js in .ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SoI8.png)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have TypeScript definition for it, you can `declare` it with type `any`:

```
declare const myfunction: any;
// ...
myfunction();
```